# wampserver http://localhost redirect to www.localhost.com

Tags: localhost, wampserver

I am using wamp server as a web server. but when I type in the URL http://localhost or 127.0.0.1, instead redirect to www.localhost.com. I've tried to restart wamp server, but the problem was happening again. is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Depending on what it is, it may be autocompleting the address when you don't want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Firefox, this procedure from [The Former Blog of cdivilly](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/disable-firefox-redirecting-to-localhost-com/) may help you with the problem:

> • Type `about:config` in the browser bar
>
> • Type `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` in the search box that appears
>
> • Right click on the `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` that appears in the filtered list below and choose Toggle to set the value to false
>
> • Problem fixed, breath out.